# How to deal with default case in an enum based switch?

Tags: java, oop, enums, switch-statement

I have an enum which evaluates wheter an string is valid, based on the enums type. The validation is performed using a switch. The default action is such:
`default: return false;`.

A programmer added a new type and forgot to update `isValid(..)`, causing calls to `isValid(..)` to return false every time an answer was evaluated.

What do you think is the proper way to deal with it?

```
public enum AnswerType {
  TEXT("string"),
  INT("integer"),
  FLOAT("float");

  final String type;

  AnswerType(final String type) {
    this.type = type;
  }

  /**
   * Checks whether the given answer is valid for this answer type.
   * @param answer The provided answer.
   * @return true if the answer is valid; false otherwise.
   */
  public boolean isValid(final String answer) {

    switch (this) {
      case TEXT:
        return !StringUtils.isEmpty(answer);

      case INT:
        return NumberUtils.isDigits(answer);

      case FLOAT:
        return NumberUtils.isNumber(answer);

      default:
        return false; // Not sure this is best practise.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If it can only hit the `default` case by mistake, throw an exception. And you could add a unit test that checks no values are missed.

Comment: Ideally, get rid of the switch statement - have an abstract method in `AnswerType` and make each enum value override it...

Comment: Resonable. Would you prefer `InternalError`, `NotImplementedException` or something else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a weird design (and the default case can't be reached with your code as it is)... Why not bring the method inside each enum constant instead?

```
public static enum AnswerType {
  TEXT("string") {
    public boolean isValid(String answer) { return !StringUtils.isEmpty(answer); }
  },
  INT("integer") {
    public boolean isValid(String answer) { return NumberUtils.isDigits(answer); }
  },
  FLOAT("float") {
    public boolean isValid(String answer) { return NumberUtils.isNumber(answer); }
  };

  private final String type;

  AnswerType(final String type) {
    this.type = type;
  }

  /**
   * Checks whether the given answer is valid for this answer type.
   *
   * @param answer The provided answer.
   *
   * @return true if the answer is valid; false otherwise.
   */
  public abstract boolean isValid(final String answer);
}
```

Alternatively, if you use Java 8, you could simplify the code further:

```
public static enum AnswerType {
  TEXT("string", s -> !StringUtils.isEmpty(s)),
  INT("integer", NumberUtils::isDigits),
  FLOAT("float", NumberUtils::isNumber);

  private final String type;
  private final Predicate<String> isValid;

  AnswerType(final String type, Predicate<String> isValid) {
    this.type = type;
    this.isValid = isValid;
  }

  /**
   * Checks whether the given answer is valid for this answer type.
   *
   * @param answer The provided answer.
   *
   * @return true if the answer is valid; false otherwise.
   */
  public boolean isValid(final String answer) {
    return isValid.test(answer);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If answer types need to be added over time, why use an enum at all? You could make an `Answer` interface with an `isValid` method and then implement it in `StringAnswer`, `IntegerAnswer`, etc. Then when someone wanted to add an answer type they would not have to modify existing code.